# Ways to traverse a matrix

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```
    for (row = vec.begin(); row != vec.end(); row++) {

        for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {


        }
}
```

So I know the first set of loops works fine, but I am not sure this one does.

```
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++){

         for (row = vec.begin(); row != vec.end(); row++){


        }
}
```

I am pretty sure it doesn't, so if that's the case, how would you go about doing something similar, that is traversing a matrix from column to column, and not from row to row.

Comment: How could the second one ever work, in the initialization for the outer loop `row` haven't even been initialized yet.

Comment: I suspected that it wouldn't work, that's why I was asking the question. It seems iterators are limited in what they can do.

Comment: It's not really a problem with the iterators, but how you want to use them. You might want to think a little about your design and what you want to be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to traverse a matrix by columns, it would make more sense to store the matrix in column major order instead of row major order, so that your first loop would actually traverse by columns instead of rows.

However, assuming that `vect` actually refers to something like `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, and that you have the same number of columns in every row, you should be able to just traverse by indexing directly. I am only posting this because you did not say you are only considering solutions with iterators.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < vec[0].size(); i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++){
        auto data = vec[j][i];          
     }
}
```

If the rows are not evenly sized, one possible solution is to pull out the max number of columns in any row beforehand.

```
size_t max_columns = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
     max_columns = max(max_columns, vec[j].size());


for (int i = 0; i < max_columns; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++){
        if (i >= vec[j].size()) continue;
        auto data = vec[j][i];          
     }
}
```

Comment: That code also assumes that the "matrix" really is a matrix, so all rows have the same number of columns.

Comment: umm what if the rows aren't evenly sized? that's why I was using iterators.

Comment: isn't that n^3? i need like n^2 and can you use a solution with the iterator instead?

Comment: The solution presented above is `O(n^2)`. I cannot imagine a clean solution using iterators (without changing the order you store the matrix), but perhaps someone else can.